# Постоянный большой объём записываемых на диск данных на сервер

Tags: java, ubuntu, apache, веб-программирование, администрирование

У меня есть VPS на ruvds за 65руб/мес (знаю цена очень низкая, но сервер для показа проектов, а не для коммерческого использования, по-этому сойдет). На нем я разворачиваю java веб-апликацию с БД и контейнером сервлетов tomcat. Постоянно приходят предупреждения о большем объеме записываемых данных. Где и что искать и как решать? Сервер на ubuntu 16.04LTS
[image: График ресурсов]

Comment: вероятно, на графиках зафиксирован обмен со swap-ом. значит, надо добавить оперативной памяти, которой, ввиду дешевизны услуг, доступно явно недостаточно для той задачи, которой вы нагрузили сервер.

Comment: А что Ваши приложения такого делают? Может Вы не закрываете какие-либо потоки и происходят дикие утечки?